# Possible to parse a HTML document and build a DOM tree(java)

Tags: java, html, dom, parsing, html-content-extraction

Is it possible and what tools could be used to parse an html document as a string or from a file and then to construct a DOM tree so that a developer can walk the tree through some API.

For example:

```
DomRoot = parse("myhtml.html");

for (tags : DomRoot) {
}
```

Note: this is a HTML document not XHtml.

Comment: please include "parsing" as a tag too

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) - it is a SAX Compliant parser that can clean malformed content such as HTML from generic web pages into well-formed XML.

```
This is <B>bold, <I>bold italic, </b>italic, </i>normal text

gets correctly rewritten as:

This is <b>bold, <i>bold italic, </i></b><i>italic, </i>normal text.
```

Comment: TagSoup is very good, especially if you have to parse crappy HTML

Answer (score 2):

[JTidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/) should let you do what you want.

Usage is fairly straight forward, but parsing is configurable. e.g.:

```
InputStream in = ...;
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
// configure Tidy instance as required
...
...
Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(in, null);
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

The JavaDoc is hosted [here](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), a Java library that performs a best effort cleaning and tag balancing in your document.  It is an easy way to parse a malformed HTML (or a non-valid XML) file.

It is distributed under the Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) seems to support conversion from HTML to XML. Then you can build a DOM tree using the usual Java toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source tools to parse HTML from Java.

Check [**http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers**](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

Also you can check answers to this question:  [Reading HTML file to DOM tree using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java)   It is almost the same...