# HTML parsing using java

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to parse a HTML document and build a DOM tree(java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433250/possible-to-parse-a-html-document-and-build-a-dom-treejava)

Hi, We use to parse the xml using DOM, SAX or JDOM. Is there any way to parse the HTML file.

ex. : main_file.html

> < div class="Main_Class" **id =
>   "main_id"**
>   style="width="100%;height="100%">
>
> ```
>   < div class="sub_class" **id = "sub_id_one"** style="width="50%;height="100%"> </div>
>   < div class="sub_class" **id = "sub_id_two"** style="width="50%;height="100%"> </div>
> ```
>
> < /div

file_two.html

> < div style="position: relative;
>   float: left; width: 24%; height:
>   100%;>
>         < input type="button"
>   class="button" value="4"/>
>   < /div

I want to parse the main file, get the sub_id and then append the the file_two.html on the basis of relativ id.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the HTML Cleaner:

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/