# Parsing HTML from a web page

Tags: java, android, html

I have to extract some information from a web page, and reformat it for the user.

Since the web page is somewhat regular, now I use HttpClient to retrive the HTML as a string, and I extract substrings in given locations with the relevant data.

Anyhow I'm wondering if there is a better way, maybe an HTML-aware way. How would you do it?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java HTML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623427/html-parsing-using-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614211/java-html-parsing

Comment: This question might be very similar to others, but it has the slight difference of being android-related which has a different set of supported libraries than java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, you should use a real HTML-parser. I've used Jsoup successfully in the past on Android:

http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 3):

I personally like to use Jericho parser: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

It is easy to use, have very much examples on project's page and deals good with pure HTML (unclosed tags etc.).

Answer (score 1):

We've used HTTPUnit do do this in the past.

Answer (score 1):

jsoup.org is better but [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) have also some addidtional features (CSS-aware and JavaScript-aware).