# How to get Started with Netbeans, WSDL and JSP

Tags: java, xml, jsp, netbeans, wsdl

I'm working on a project and I need to use some webservices, such as Global Weather, to add to the service..

I'm using NetBeans, and Currently I can use this Web Service to call Weather + Cities By Country Name:
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

Anyway, so this is what I'm doing now:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Weather Finder</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Weather Test</h1>    <%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
    <%
    try {
    net.webservicex.GlobalWeather service = new net.webservicex.GlobalWeather();
    net.webservicex.GlobalWeatherSoap port = service.getGlobalWeatherSoap();
    java.lang.String countryName = "Australia";
    java.lang.String result = port.getCitiesByCountry(countryName);
    out.println("Result = "+result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    %>
    <%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>

       <%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
    <%
    try {
    net.webservicex.GlobalWeather service = new net.webservicex.GlobalWeather();
    net.webservicex.GlobalWeatherSoap port = service.getGlobalWeatherSoap();
    java.lang.String cityName = "Melbourne";
    java.lang.String countryName = "Australia";
    java.lang.String result = port.getWeather(cityName, countryName);
    out.println("Result = "+result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
    %>
    <%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Which Returns:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Weather Finder</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>    <hr/>
        Result = <NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Archerfield Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Amberley Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Alice Springs Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Brisbane Airport M. O</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Coolangatta Airport Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Cairns Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Charleville Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Gladstone</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Longreach Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mount Isa Amo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mackay Mo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Oakey Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Proserpine Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Rockhampton Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Broome Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Townsville Amo</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Weipa City</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Gove Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Tennant Creek Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Yulara Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Albury Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Devonport East</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Goldstream Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>East Sale Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Hobart Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Launceston Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Laverton Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Moorabbin Airport Aws</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mount Gambier Aerodrome</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Mildura Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
        <City>Melbourne Airport</City>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Macquarie Island</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Wynyard West</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Adelaide Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Albany Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Broken Hill Patton Street</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Ceduna Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Derby</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Darwin Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Bullsbrook Pearce Amo</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Edinburgh M. O.</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Forrest Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Geraldton Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Kalgoorlie Boulder Amo</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Kununurra Kununurra Aws</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Leigh Creek Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Learmonth Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Meekatharra Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Port Hedland Pardoo</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Parafield Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Belmont Perth Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Katherine Aerodrome</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Woomera Aerodrome</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Bankstown Airport Aws</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Canberra</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Coffs Harbour Mo</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Cooma</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Camden Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Dubbo</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Norfolk Island Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Nowra Ran Air Station</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Richmond Aus-Afb</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Sydney Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Tamworth Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Wagga Airport</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Australia</Country>
    <City>Williamtown Aerodrome</City>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>


    <hr/>

       <hr/>
    Result = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Melbourne Airport, Australia (YMML) 37-40S 144-50E 141M</Location>
  <Time>Sep 19, 2011 - 07:39 AM EDT / 2011.09.19 1139 UTC</Time>
  <Wind> from the WSW (240 degrees) at 29 MPH (25 KT):0</Wind>
  <Visibility> greater than 7 mile(s):0</Visibility>
  <SkyConditions> mostly cloudy</SkyConditions>
  <Temperature> 57 F (14 C)</Temperature>
  <DewPoint> 44 F (7 C)</DewPoint>
  <RelativeHumidity> 62%</RelativeHumidity>
  <Pressure> 29.53 in. Hg (1000 hPa)</Pressure>
  <Status>Success</Status>
</CurrentWeather>


    <hr/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Which is Great, But how do I get all that XML Information back into my Java Application so I can put it somewhere useful?

For example, how to I change the Result of the Weather into something more useful like an Array? Or ArrayList and call it somewhere else in my Application.

Thank you!

Comment: On a side note, you may want to read this answer by BalusC on using scriptlets in JSP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Comment: How could I use JSTL in this situation?

Comment: I would suggest looking more at EL here. the only thing you display is the result, which could easily be placed in a request attribute before displaying your JSP.

Comment: But how do I take that Result, and Use it in my application?

Comment: I'm more curious into how I can take that Result XML string from `port.getWeather(cityName, countryName)` and use it throughout my Application, with CSS styling etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily transform (parse) the `result` XML into a meaningful java object corresponding to the schema of the web service's result (see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/mapping/), and pass it along to a service in your application. Then operate as you want on you (list of) java objects.

Comment: I come from a PHP background - I can't believe that I have to implement a custom class just to get some simple info from a damn XML string? Why is Java So Complex? Isn't there a way to convert the XML from above into an Array that can be called such as MyArray["Weather"]??

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [Reading HTML file to DOM tree using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java)
The solution can be applied in your case also(Parse the HTML to Dom tree and then operate on it)