# java.io.FileNotFoundException, what is the error?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a file and print out a substring of each line. I cant figure out what my error is. My link works, so what is causing the error?

```html
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
public class FileReader {
 public void fileReader() {
  File file = newFile("https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/14F/cis212/assignments/phonebook.txt");
  try{
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
  while(scan.hasNextLine())
  {
   String numAndName = scan.nextLine();
   String newNum = numAndName.substring(0, 8);
   System.out.println(newNum);
  }
  scan.close();
  } catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FileNotFoundException == The file... wasn't found. Error 404. It's just not there.

In this case, you didn't specify a file, you specified a webpage - it doesn't work like that, you need to use network-related classes to download the page before you can interact with it.

the `File` class is purely for files on your harddrive (or connected USBs / disks / etc).

Check out [How to read a text from a web page with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825798/how-to-read-a-text-from-a-web-page-with-java) for help reading webpages. (The question itself has what you're looking for, the answers are more advanced interaction.)

Answer (score 1):

```
new File("https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/14F/cis212/assignments/phonebook.txt");
```

The problem is the filename. That isn't a filename, it's a URL, and it doesn't refer to a file, it refers to an HTTP resource. Remove it, and change this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
```

to this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new URL("https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/14F/cis212/assignments/phonebook.txt").openStream());
```

E&OE