# Calling a webpage without opening it from processing

Tags: java, firebase, client-server, processing

I'm totally desperate trying to do this. I Started a new job where I was given an app made in Processing and now I need it to call a simple index.html(https://west-4f2bc.firebaseapp.com) but not opening it on the browser.

Is there anyway to do it?
later I'm going to pass data adding parameters in URL but now I just need to call it as it is without a window opening.

Please Help me.....
I tried a lot of variants of this code

```
import processing.net.*; 
Client myClient; 

void setup() { 
  // Connect to the local machine at port 10002.
  // This example will not run if you haven't
  // previously started a server on this port.
  myClient = new Client(this, "west-4f2bc.firebaseapp.com", 80); 
  // Say hello
  myClient.write("GET /\r\n");
} 

void draw() { 

}
```

Thanks.

With this I only get true, so it connects but I only get 0.

```
import processing.net.*; 

Client myClient; 
int dataIn; 

void setup() { 
  size(200, 200); 
  // Connect to the local machine at port 5204.
  // This example will not run if you haven't
  // previously started a server on this port.
  myClient = new Client(this, "west-4f2bc.firebaseapp.com", 80); 
  println(myClient.active());
  println(dataIn);
} 

void draw() { 

}
```

with this I get connected but after Client SocketException: Socket closed

```
import processing.net.*; 

Client myClient; 
int dataIn; 

void setup() { 
  Client client;
  client = new Client(this, "west-4f2bc.firebaseapp.com", 80);

  if (client.active()==true) {
    println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.write("GET /call.html?id=ola&nome=artur\r\n");
    client.write("\r\n");
    client.stop();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    println("connection failed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never really used Processing's Networking library, but from what I can tell it's not usually used to read data from a website- it's used for lower-level communication between a client and server. It might be possible to use it to read a website, but what you have already looks more complicated than it has to be.

Remember that Processing is built on top of Java, so anything you can do in Java, you can do in Processing. If I were you, I would do a google search for "java read website" for a ton of results, including:

- [Reading Directly from a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)
- [How to read a text file directly from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6259339/873165)
- [Reading website's contents into string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5867975/873165)
- [How to read a text from a web page with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9825798/873165)
- [Using Java to pull data from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6159118/873165)

Comment: I don't read the website. I just want to call it without open the page. To send parameters later. Like www.example.com/?Id=something&name=something and then pass that value to variables

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues The process is the same. Google something like "java post to url" for a ton of results.

Answer (score 0):

I used another library.

```
import http.requests.*;

void setup()
{
  size (100, 100);
}

void draw()
{
  PostRequest post = new PostRequest("https://"+"www.example.com");                             

  post.send();

  System.out.println("Reponse Content: " + post.getContent());
  System.out.println("Reponse Content-Length Header: " + post.getHeader("Content-Length"));

  noLoop();
}
```

Still doesnt does my final objective but at least it can communicate with the page.