# "document" is not defined in <eval> java ScriptEngine

Tags: java, javascript-engine

i'm trying to call document in java using scriptEngine here is my code

```
     ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager=new ScriptEngineManager();
     ScriptEngine scriptEngine=scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    scriptEngine.eval("function func(){" +
    "document.location.href=someUrl;" +
                  "var text=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];"}"
                    );
            Invocable invocable= (Invocable) scriptEngine;
            ((Invocable) scriptEngine).invokeFunction("func");
```

it throws an exception

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script engine in Java provides the ability to execute Javascript code, but does not provide an emulation of a browser.

`document`, `window` and other objects are defined by the browsers but are not mandated to be present by ECMAScript specification (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15).

Comment: You don't need javascript to do that. Use HTTP clients like https://github.com/square/okhttp or https://hc.apache.org/ to download the **raw HTML** of the page. That will NOT give you the DOM of the page as you would expect in a browser, though (which you would not get in a script engine either). To obtain the DOM from the raw html text, check for example this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java

Comment: thank you. I want to load document and  add EventListener for button programmatically, that's why i'm using javascript.