# Redirect to another servlets path through Java Method

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I have a method inside my doGet that starts a thread if the date is not equal to today. The scheduler will find the execute() method. Inside this method() I try to use the redirect.

**Method 1:**
I used the ScriptEngine to call my js method through Java but it always gives me the following error:

Js method:

```
function httpGet(theUrl){
window.open(theUrl)
}
```

Java Method:

```
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
              // read script file

              engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(url), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
              Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
              // call function from script file
              inv.invokeFunction("httpGet", "http://localhost:8080/myProject/StartScript?duration="+minutes);
```

Error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined in <eval> at line number 3
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:392)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
at watering.WateringScheduler.execute(WateringScheduler.java:99)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)Caused by: <eval>:3 ReferenceError: "window" is not defined
```

**Method 2:**

I tried to use HttpUrlConnection but the problem is that it never redirects me to the page even though it connects.

```
 URL url;
              log.info("hi "+ minutes);
              url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myProject/StartScript?duration="+minutes);
              HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
              urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
              urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
              urlConnection.connect();
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
              int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
              System.out.println(responseCode);
              if(responseCode==200) {
                  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                  System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + url);
              }
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    html.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
```

The problem is that everything I read online points to redirect through the doGet or doPost. I want to redirect through my execute() method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The script engine in Java provides the ability to execute Javascript code, but does not provide an emulation of a browser.
Use HTTP clients like [okhttp](http://github.com/square/okhttp) to download the raw HTML of the page.

For more information please visit
[“document” is not defined in  java ScriptEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744204/document-is-not-defined-in-eval-java-scriptengine)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. If I have a getMethod to the url that I want to call will it execute it or it will just print its content?

Comment: You can use JSP scheduler and Servlets to achieve this functionality.

Comment: That's exactly what I am using. The servlet that I try to redirect to holds a doGet method. If I understand correctly okttp prints the http section of the page, it does not redirect you to the actual page.

Comment: In the doGet you can first check if the date is today, and start scheduler and when timeout will occur just call response.sendRedirect("/toyoururl");

Comment: This is the first part that I implement. The second part stores the date in a database and executes the thread when the stored date is equal to Calendars day. This thread must then call my doGet to do everything...

Comment: Introduce a new Servlet and implement database logic in that and call that servlet using
`RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");
rd.forward(request,response);`

Comment: Didn't know about that. The problem again with that is that the method that must be implemented is either a doPost or a doGet. I am trying to do that through an execute method that does not hold an HttpServletRequest request.

Comment: What does your execute method looks like?  If its helper method you can invoke it from doGet as well.

Comment: My execute method is the execute() method of Quartz scheduler.

Comment: You can easily call execute method from doGet or doPost.
You can also use QuartzInitializerServlet
or please have a look at this.
 https://www.splinter.com.au/using-quartz-scheduler-in-a-java-web-app-serv/

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look and update you with the results! Thank you for your time!